# Moving Codigniter from windows server to Linux based server

Tags: linux, codeigniter, dojo

I have moved a CodeIgniter based site from a Windows based server to a Linux based server. I have had various issues. Currently I am stuck on images failing to upload. (server timeout error)

Steps taken:
Set uploads folder to 777.
Try php 5.4 & 5.2.
I was looking for a suspected temp folder somewhere, but not finding one.
I have searched, and found an article discussing CodeIgniter timing out after 300s. But in my case, it times out almost immediately upload is initiated. File attempting to upload is 41kb.
I have checked php settings, max_input_time: 60, upload_max_filesize: 64M, post_max_size: 64M
Not sure what else I can add.

After more searching, and some tests, it is more than likely a conflict between Ajax and CI. A normal php upload works. I found a few articles discussing issues with CI and Ajax. Unfortunately, they dont seem to match my code.

And more:
I found some log files. They do correspond to what I did on the website.
The first line is the last line displaying action of refreshing web page and time taken.
The following lines are for click on browse for image and click upload.
Interesting is a couple of ignored attempts to load files.

```
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 01:58:43 --> Total execution time: 0.0495
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Helper loaded: sql_date_helper
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Helper loaded: form_helper
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Native_session Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Session class already loaded. Second attempt ignored.
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Cart Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Encrypt Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Template Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> MY Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 02:00:10 --> Encrypt class already loaded. Second attempt ignored.
```

More Info: 11 Jun 2015:

After much searching, I think this is not a CodeIgniter Issue. It appears to be an issue with Dojo.
I found this within the product.php file

```
if (!$this->ajaxupload->do_upload('flashUploadFiles'))
```

Somewhere in this file there should be settings for Dojo, but I cannot find them. Dont know what I am looking for really. The help on the Dojo website seems really confusing. I also supect that there is more than just upload the Dojo files and put some code in the correct place to activate it. I wonder if there is something that has to be activated on the server.

I have also added Dojo to the Tags List

Comment: you've to check if your problem is CI related or not;
for this purpose try to create a simple html form without CI and submit the file you wish to upload to the server - if this works you know this is a CI problem - otherwise you have a server related issue

Comment: Simple upload tested, and works OK.

Comment: ok, then you should show us your CI Code
and the result of `print_r($_FILES); `

Answer (score 0):

The error may be related to permission,
just follow the steps, these may help you

1. check you base_url in config.php file and other path for uplaoding (if given).
2. Check that all images and assets used in codeigniter are with project folder, not anywehere else in your computer.
3. You should have a folder in root of your project named like assets, and its permission should be 777 hiearchically for all folders and files.
4. Permission for 'application' and 'system' folder should be 755 also for all folders within it, and for all files in it , permission should be 644.
5. if problem not solved, check images path, may be it is refering to any location to you computer, if path statically bee used. you should manage this.
6. If your url got changed, change it also in .htacces file.

Comment: 1. base url & path changed: must be right, the whole site works except for uploading images in admin area.
2. As above, everything works, all images display correctly.
3. No assets folder anywhere
4. Permissions correct.
5. Images path appears correct also, as all images display.
6. Url is same after nameservers changed

I am pretty sure it is related to a temp upload location and permissions regarding it. I dont know enough about CodeIgniter to know where this would be stored. Done searching, found nothing.

I didn't build the site, and honestly find CI very confusing.

Comment: try this if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field_name)) { echo $this->upload->display_errors(); die(); }, may be you find better error message.

Comment: Not sure where this is supposed to go, tried it in the config.php file, a few lines after the !defined('BASEPATH')

Site just went blank, so reverted

Comment: in controller, $this->upload->do_upload() is being used to move file from temp location to desired location, find this code where code is submitting then try this.

Comment: I did a full text search on all files...  
$this->upload appears in the file system/libraries/Upload.php  
do_upload() does not appear in any files (text search on all files)  
  
There is a constants.php file which has "define('FILE_READ_MODE', 0644);   
define('FILE_WRITE_MODE', 0666);   
define('DIR_READ_MODE', 0755);   
define('DIR_WRITE_MODE', 0777);"   
Should these be different on a non windows server?

Comment: As an extra, there seems to be some kind of ajax upload addon

Comment: I found this article. Trying to make sense of it.  http://www.hiretheworld.com/blog/tech-blog/codeigniter-session-race-conditions

Comment: yes, if  do_upload() is not in any file, then may be any library or jquery plugin in being used to upload files. So this error may related to that plugin, just find plugin or library then read its requirements and compatibility for different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I had a Freelancer work on this for me, It turned out to be a Session timeout set too short.

Thanks for all who took the time to answer or read.